# Tukey hsd test vs DMS test

Tags: generalized-linear-model, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I am analyzing the differences on my dataset. This dataset has different values according to each group (called season_sized). I have no normality and heterocedasticity, so I performed a GLM to fit my dataset . With the result of the GLM I performed an anova and a post hoc test, which was Tukey hsd test.  However, a workmate suggested to me make a DMS instead a Tukey hsd. I would like to know what advantages have the tukey test with reference to a DMS.